# Gson: Deserialize and "extend" a huge JSON

Tags: java, kotlin, gson, json-deserialization

I have a huge Trello's JSON which a I need transform in another JSON with different structure. In order to do that I use Gson for deserializing and serializing in the output format but the input JSON has keys with just the ids values who actually are defined as elements in others JSON parts in a "decoupled" way. That structure makes difficult deserialice an link the objects without codify an specific and long deserializer. Any way to do this in an easy way?

Input JSON:

```
{
  "id": "5edf568cd37bf379d96640b3",
  "name": "Trello board",
  // A LOT ENTRIES...
  "lists": [{
      "id": "5edf568dabadcf538c546c3c",
      "name": "TO DO"
  },{
      "id": "5edf568dfd9cb03d1c346cbf",
      "name": "IN PROGRESS" 
  }],
  "cards": [{
    "desc": "Card 1"
    "idList": "5edf568dfd9cb03d1c346cbf", // This should be deserialized with the specific "lists" element
     // A LOT ENTRIES...
  },{
    "desc": "Card 2"
    "idList": "5edf568dfd9cb03d1c346cbf",
     // A LOT ENTRIES...
  }],
  // A LOT ENTRIES...
}
```

Current POJOs:

```kotlin
data class TrelloList(val id: String, val name: String)
data class Card(val desc: String, val idList: String)
```

Desired Card POJO

```kotlin
data class Card(val desc: String, val list: TrelloList)
```

How can I extend or convert that ids into the related objects without codify a complete custom deserializer?

Comment: I'd suggest to use a Streaming API?

Comment: You should first deserialize it using Trello's structure. _Then_ convert the format into another data class. If you want to convert the JSON itself while deserializing, you'd _have_ to write a deserializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I had to write a custom deserializer. It's a pity Gson does not count with an structural Jsons adapter or something to make joins between elements with same ids.